# Refactoring where clause

Tags: haskell, monads, parsec

I am learnig Haskell, so it's probably something pretty trivial, but I would appreciate some pointers on how to rewrite it and how it works.

I have following working code (used packages: [HTF](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTF), [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) and [Flow](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/flow)):

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF htfpp #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Main where

import Test.Framework -- assertEqual, assertBool, htfMain, htf_thisModulesTests
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec (eof, spaces, parse)
import Flow ((|>))
import Data.Either (isLeft)

whiteSpaces = spaces

test_parse_whitespace = do
  mapM_ positive [
      "", " ", "\t", "\n", "\r\n", "  \r\n  ",
      "   \t   \r\n  \t  \n   \r  \t "
    ]
  mapM_ negative ["x",  " x",  "x ",  " x ",  "\t_\t"]
  where
    parser = whiteSpaces >> eof
    parseIt = parse parser ""
    positive str = assertEqual (parseIt str) (Right ())
    negative str = assertBool (parseIt str |> isLeft)

main :: IO ()
main = htfMain htf_thisModulesTests
```

I am adding a new test which have almost same the  where part, so I tried to refactor it like this:

```
pos_neg_case parser = do
  return [positive, negative]
  where
    fullParser = parser >> eof
    parseIt = parse fullParser ""
    positive str = assertEqual (parseIt str) (Right ())
    negative str = assertBool (parseIt str |> isLeft)

test_parse_whitespace' = do
  mapM_ positive [
      "", " ", "\t", "\n", "\r\n", "  \r\n  ",
      "   \t   \r\n  \t  \n   \r  \t "
    ]
  mapM_ negative ["x",  " x",  "x ",  " x ",  "\t_\t"]
  where
    [positive, negative] = pos_neg_case whiteSpaces
```

Which doesn't work (even when I turn the lang. feature on as compiler suggests).

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char] -> m b0’
            with actual type ‘[String -> IO ()]’
Relevant bindings include
  test_parse_whitespace' :: m () (bound at test/Spec.hs:21:1)
In the first argument of ‘mapM_’, namely ‘positive’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  mapM_ positive ["", " ", "\t", "\n", ....]

Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char] -> m b1’
            with actual type ‘[String -> IO ()]’
Relevant bindings include
  test_parse_whitespace' :: m () (bound at test/Spec.hs:21:1)
In the first argument of ‘mapM_’, namely ‘negative’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  mapM_ negative ["x", " x", "x ", " x ", ....]
```

Comment: `assertEqual` and `assertBool` are from the [*HTF*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTF-0.13.1.0/docs/Test-Framework-HUnitWrapper.html) package, while `(|>)` is from [*flow*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/flow-1.0.7/docs/Flow.html) and is just a synonym for `flip ($)` and `(&)`. (Mentioning the not-so-well-known packages that you are using makes for clearer questions.)

Comment: @duplode Oh, thank you (I thought imports were enough). I knew *flow* isn't much popular among Haskellers, but *HTF* isn't too? Is there some better alternative which can run all unit tests in a module without boilerplate?

Comment: "I thought imports were enough" -- They are enough in the sense that they provide enough information to search for and eventually find them and the relevant functions. It is just a matter of convenience for readers of the question. (I have nothing to say against any of the packages you have used.)

Comment: Actually, thinking about what I just said, I think you are right: I was a touch too pedantic/demanding in asking for links to packages that are available from Hackage, given that you correctly mentioned the module names. Your question was just fine. If you feel like making it easier for those who read your question, use explicit import lists (e.g. `import Test.Framework (assertEqual, assertBool)`). They also have the advantage of making it easier for you to recall which module provided each thing, should you need to read again your code at some point in the future.

Comment: I think you are right, this question is from/for beginners, so stating imports explicitly and having links to packages is IMO a nice touch. I have updated it that way. (That HTF is using some meta magic, couldn't make explicit imports to work -_-*.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noticed, the problem was the `return` you added to:

```
pos_neg_case parser = do
  return [positive, negative]
  where -- etc.
```

The type of `mapM_` is:

```
GHCi> :t mapM_
mapM_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m ()
```

`positive` and `negative` are functions which already have appropriate types to be passed to `mapM`, and so if you want `pos_neg_case` to give them back as a list you don't need to do anything more than wrapping in a list. `return` is not a keyword; it is just a function that injects a value into a monadic context. If you don't need to do any such injection, you don't need `return`.

P.S.: Quoting your answer:

> But I had to guess the Parser type, hole was giving me very complex thingy 
>   `Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a -> [s -> IO ()]`.

This is an example of a quite common pattern. `ParsecT` is a type constructor with quite a few type variables, and `Parser` is a type synonym for a common set of choices of some of these variables, which allows for tidier type signatures which do not mention them explicitly. If you look for it in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Prim.html#t:Parser) (the index helps a lot in such cases) or use `:info` in GHCi, you will find that `Parser` just means...

```
type Parser = Parsec String ()
```

... and `Parsec`, in turn is...

```
type Parsec s u = ParsecT s u Identity
```

... so that expanding the `Parser` synonym gives `ParsecT String () Identity`, which is what GHC told you when you introduced the type hole.

Comment: Thank you for explanation :).

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure about those monads, but I got it somehow working (those `_` aka typeholes helped a lot, didn't know about them).

```
pos_neg_case :: Parser a -> [String -> IO ()]
pos_neg_case parser = [positive, negative]
  where
    fullParser = parser >> eof
    parseIt = parse fullParser ""
    positive str = assertEqual (parseIt str) (Right ())
    negative str = assertBool (parseIt str |> isLeft)
```

But I had to guess the Parser type, hole was giving me very complex thingy - `Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a -> [s -> IO ()]`.